# How to store Multiple List objects into file ? and e.printStackTrace() vs e.getMessage()

Tags: java, oop

**ObjectOutputStream**
Firstly, how to read multiple list objects from a file ? and secondly i used Object class object to read the objects' bytes stream (is it a good way ?) but when i use e.printStackTrace, it gives me excpetion and with e.getmessage, it doesnt give any exception.

```
public void WriterIntoFile() {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(10);
        list.add(60);
        list.add(90);
        list.add(10);
        list.add(40);
        list.add(30);
        list.add(20);
        List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
        list1.add("A");
        list1.add("B");
        list1.add("D");
        list1.add("U");
        list1.add("L");
        list1.add("L");
        list1.add("A");
        list1.add("H");
        try {
            writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            writer.writeObject(list);
            writer.writeObject(list1);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void readFromFile() {
        try {
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            Object obj;
            while ((obj = reader.readObject()) != null) {
                System.out.println(obj);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
[10, 60, 90, 10, 40, 30, 20]
[A, B, D, U, L, L, A, H]
java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3225)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1695)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:514)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:472)
    at com.newexample.Files.readFromFile(Files.java:56)
    at com.newexample.ManageFiles.main(ManageFiles.java:9)
```

**e.getMessage()**

```
public void readFromFile() {
            try {
                reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                Object obj;
                while ((obj = reader.readObject()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(obj);
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
```

**Output**

```
[10, 60, 90, 10, 40, 30, 20]
[A, B, D, U, L, L, A, H]
```

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` will print the stack trace, that's why you see it. `e.getMessage();` returns the message, but then you don't do anything with it and discard it, that's why you don't see the exception. Read the method descriptions in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).

Comment: ok but does it mean that my code is working correctly ?

Comment: Only you can say that, does the code do what **you** want it to do? It writes, then it reads successfully, [EOFException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) signifies the end of the stream, it looks like it does the job.

Comment: No, the fact that a stack trace is printed means that your code is not working correctly. The documentation of `readObject` does not say that it returns `null` if it reaches the end of the file. In fact, it never returns null; at the end of the file, it throws an exception. You should catch the exception (as you already do), check if it is EOFExcecption (which is expected) and exit instead of printing a stack trace.

Comment: yeah it was an EOFException, I removed the while condidtion and now it is working without any exception. Thankyou....